# Is there an easy way to check if my python 3.6 script is compatible with python 2.7?

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to test whether code developed in Python 3.6 will be compatible with Python 2.7. Ideally - if not I would like to have the invalid syntax pointed out in some way. Thank you

Comment: There’s no way to provide a guarantee. The hard parts aren’t syntax.

Comment: If `3to2` produces an identical script, chances are.

Comment: aside from syntax or features that 2 vs 3 may have different or missing, testing is what you should involve in your development cycle. Then you will know. Also  static analysis would help.

Comment: In how far is the obvious "just run it with 2.7" not sufficient for your use case? Do you care only about syntax, or the standard library as well?

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Execute your code with `python2.7 yourScript.py`. If some modules need python3.*, you could write a second script only for python2.7? Hacky but it's the quick and lazy solution.

You should definitely check the version on startup. This snippet restartes the script automatically with the right version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# pythonVersionCheck.py

import sys
import os

# Color codes for output
CRED = '\033[91m'
CGREEN = '\033[92m'
CEND = '\033[0m'

# Desired python version number
scriptVersion = "3.6"

# Check if script is executed with root. Get rid of this block if you don't need it
if os.geteuid() != 0:
    print(CRED + "\nRestart the script with root privileges: 'sudo python" 
    + scriptVersion + " " + sys.argv[0] + "'\n" + CEND)
    sys.exit(0)

# Check if the script is running with the desired python version
if sys.version[:3] == scriptVersion:
    print(CGREEN + "Script running with Python " + scriptVersion + CEND)
else:
    print(CRED + "Script not running with Python " + scriptVersion + ". Restarting." + CEND)
    try:
         os.execv(sys.executable, ['python' + scriptVersion] + sys.argv)
    except OSError as error:
        print(CRED + "An error occured: " + str(error) + CEND)

# YOUR CODE HERE
```

Read up on portability between Python2.* and Python3.* [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html).

**EDIT:** As suggested by @MisterMiyagi, here some changes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# pythonVersionCheck.py

import sys
import subprocess
import platform

# Desired python version number
scriptVersion = "2.7"
usedVersion = "{0}.{1}".format(sys.version_info.major,sys.version_info.minor)
opSys = platform.system()

# Check if the script is running with the desired python version
if usedVersion == scriptVersion:
    print("Script running with Python " + scriptVersion)
else:
    print("Script not running with Python " + scriptVersion + ". Restarting.")
    if opSys == 'Linux' or opSys == 'Darwin':
        subprocess.call('python' + scriptVersion + ' ' + sys.path[0] + '/' +
        sys.argv[0], shell=True)
    elif opSys is 'Windows':
        print("py -" + scriptVersion + ' ' + sys.argv[0])
        subprocess.call("py -" + scriptVersion + ' ' + sys.argv[0], shell=True)
    else:
        print("Can't detect os.")

# YOUR CODE HERE
```

It now uses `subprocess` instead of `os.execv`.
It now uses `sys.version_info` instead of `sys.version`.
It now checks what platform the user runs so now it is portable to Linux, Windows and Appletoshwin.

Comment: Asking just out of curiosity, is there a reason why you write `str("3.6")` instead of just `"3.6"`? Does it help anything, is it a convention of any kind, or just a personal habit?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It doesn't matter in this case, you're absolutely right! `>>> scriptVersion = str("3.6")
>>> type(scriptVersion)
<class 'str'>
>>> scriptVersion = "3.6"
>>> type(scriptVersion)
<class 'str'>`

Comment: Please don't handle portability like this! 1) It is UNIX only, not a chance on Windows. 2) It works for PATH lookups only, without taking into account virtual environments and the like. 3) Missing privileges is an error, exit code 0 is inappropriate. 4) It does not (and cannot) check whether the user explicitly requested a different Python version. 5) It will refuse to run on compatible versions, such as 3.7, 3.8, .... 6). 6) Using ``sys.version`` and ``os.execv`` is archaic for this problem. Use ``sys.version_info`` and ``subprocess``. Do not do custom error handling that swallows details.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for the criticism. I don't know how to take virtual envs into account and for #4, I think the goal was to set a version number that should be used for the script so the user will automatically run the right one. I will post the edit with `sys.version_info` and `subprocess` in a minute. Do you mind to explain why using those is better?

Comment: @anonjnr sys.version_info provides a namedtuple, so you can actually do a numerical major/minor/patch comparison. sys.version_info[:3] >= (3,6,0) would support 3.6, 3.7, and so on, even a hypothetical 3.10 and beyond. subprocess does proper creation, teardown and error handling.